# How to get time difference as minutes in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I have time values in two cells in an Excel sheet and I need the difference of
the times in minutes.

The cells in the Excel are like below:

```
   A        B        C
1  6:38     8:23     1:45:00
```

A is the start time
B is the end time
C is the time difference (B1-A1) which is displayed in **hh:mm:ss** format

A and B cols are formatted as custom hh:mm and cell C is formatted as custom **hh:mm:ss**.

But I need to get in the value in cell C1 as **105** instead of **1:45:00**.

Could you please help in displaying time only in minutes and giving the right format?

Comment: In case you still care after almost 6 years: I added some examples to [Neal's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/89045/how-to-get-time-difference-as-minutes-in-excel/369936#369936), which does not need any formulas.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just set the cell to be shown in numerical format and it will show a decimal number.

The integer part corresponds to the date value (i.e. the day) and the decimal part to the time of the day.

If you multiply the numerical value of 1:45 (which is 0,07) by 24x60 (the number of hours in a day and the number of minutes in an hour) you will obtain the value in minutes of your cell (105).

Comment: Instead of additional calculations, I'd prefer to use formatting, like in [Neal's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/89045/how-to-get-time-difference-as-minutes-in-excel/369936#369936).

Answer (score 17):

Just format your cell as `[mm]`.

The square brackets around the `mm` tell Excel to show the total rather than what would be shown if you took the total hours off. The brackets also force Excel to interpret `mm` as minutes, not as the month. (Without the brackets, `m` and `mm` [refer to the month](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4) if not preceded by `h` or `hh` for hours or followed by `ss` for seconds.)

So, where `1:45:00` with format `mm:ss` would ignore the hours and show `45:00`, both `[m]:ss` and `[mm]:ss` will show as `105:00`, and both `[m]` and `[mm]` would show `105` (where `m` and `mm` would show `12`, being the *month* of Excel's default date, which [is](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-bd549d1c-f829-4691-a77d-4a1e3d42bc1a) December 31, 1899).

This also works for hours and seconds. Like `27:10:59` with `h:mm` would show `3:10`, but both `[h]:mm` and `[hh]:mm` show `27:10`, while both `[h]` and `[hh]` show `27`. And `s` would show `59`, but `[s]` gives `97859`.

[image]

Comment: So lets suppose I've a cell that has both date & 24hr-time like 2018-09-25 15:40:33 ...refer to http://prntscr.com/ip2b1t Using your suggestion in column C I split date from time & convert it to TOTAL secs. In column A I want to have a cumulative rising duration (in secs) & I have achieved it as shown in figure by assigning 0 to A1 then assigning `=A1+(C2-C1)` to A2. Is there any other alternative to skip intermediate calculation in column C

Answer (score 13):

I think this will work:

- A1 6:23
- B1 8:23
- C1 =(B1-A1)*24*60

Just make sure you format C1 as "General"

Answer (score 0):

Just format your C cell as `hh:mm`.

Comment: Or, to show 28 hours as `28`, not `04`, surround with square brackets: `[hh]:mm`.

Answer (score 0):

As some people have already said,
If you multiply the numerical value of 1:45 (which is 0,07) by 24x60=1440 (the number of hours in a day and the number of minutes in an hour) you will obtain the value in minutes of your cell (105).
Short version: C1 =(B1-A1)*1440